# Webforms Upload de múltiplos arquivos

Tags: c#, webforms, file-upload

Tenho uma aplicação `WebForms` que precisa receber múltiplos arquivos que estarão associados com um tipo específico do meu sistema.

Ex:

**Tipo**: [Carteira de motorista] | **Arquivo**: img001.png 
**Tipo**: [Comprovante de residência] | **Arquivo**: comp001.pdf

Preciso receber essas informações em uma página `WebForm` `.aspx`.

Se fosse só para pegar os arquivos, podeira pegar usando o `Request.Files`, porém preciso saber o Tipo do documento para poder salvar no banco.

Imaginei em fazer algo do como utilizar o nome dos campos de arquivos como um `array` utilizando `arquivos[0]`, `arquivos[1]` e associar com o de tipos (`tipos[0]`, `tipos[1]`). Fazendo assim poderia utilizar os index que eu poderia garantir que o tipo seria relacionado ao arquivo. Porém não sei como acessar essas informações na páginas `.aspx`.

Com MVC consigo fazer isso de boa, mas como não tenho o domínio com o `WebForms` acabo me batendo um pouco com isso.

Como eu poderia fazer isso de uma forma sem "Gambiarras"?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Basta user múltiplos componentes do tipo `asp:FileUpload` e acessá-los usando seus respectivos nome no evento desejado seguindo o exemplo abaixo;

```cs
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false"/>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" AllowMultiple="false"/>
```

```cs
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        var file1info = FileUpload1.FileName + " - " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + " Bytes.";
        //logica para salvar
    }

    if(FileUpload2.HasFile)
    {
        var file2info = FileUpload2.FileName + " - " + FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength + " Bytes.";
        //logica para salvar
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso isso teria que ser dinâmico. E eu tbm não quero que o cliente tenha que esperar fazer o reload da página para adicionar um novo campo. Eu iria replicar os campos utilizando `JS`

Comment: Neste formato ambos os arquivos vão subir em um único post, não entendi sua objeção

Comment: É que eu posso ter 1 ou N arquivos. Não vou ter um número fixo de arquivos

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que nesse caso um Repeater seja o ideal. Com o Repeater você poderá criar vários controles (FileUpload), tem um índice de cada item e depois efetuar a validação.

1. Criar update Panel para ter um melhor controle do conteudo e evitar refresh na página toda;
2. Criar um botão de upload para validar e enviar os arquivos;
3. Criar um repeater para mostrar dinamicamente os controles;
4. Colocar os controle de FileUpad dentro do repeater;
5. Criar um HiddenField pra aguardar o Índice do item;
6. Criar trigger para o botão de upload (evitar que o arquivo inserido no FileUpload perca a informação no postback);

Segue um exemplo funcional. Espero que ajude.

**Página ASPX**

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Enviar" ID="lblEnviar" OnClick="lblEnviar_Click" runat="server" />
            <br />

            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    File Upload <%# Eval("TipoDocumento") %>
                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnIndex" Visible="false" Value='<%# Eval("Index") %>' />
                    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuArquivos" AllowMultiple="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>


        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lblEnviar" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="ltlResultado" runat="server" />
```

**Arquivo ASPX.CS**

```
       //Objeto para fazer o transporte das informações
    public class DTO
    {
        public int Index { get; set; } //armazenar a posicao
        public string TipoDocumento { get; set; } //Descritivo do tipo do documento
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Simula uma chamada ao banco e carrega uma lista com os tipos necessários a serem enviados
        List<DTO> lst = new List<DTO>();

        lst.Add(new DTO() { Index = 0, TipoDocumento = "CNH" });
        lst.Add(new DTO() { Index = 1, TipoDocumento = "CPF" });

        //Popula o Repeater
        rpt.DataSource = lst;
        rpt.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lblEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //verifica cada linha gerada no repeater
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
        {
            //Procurar o controle FileUpload
            FileUpload fuTemp = (FileUpload)item.FindControl("fuArquivos");

            //Procurar identificador 
            HiddenField hdnIndex = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnIndex");

            //Verifica se tem arquivo
            if (fuTemp.HasFile)
            {
                string s = String.Format("O arquivo na posição {0}, tem o seguinte arquivo {1}", hdnIndex.Value, fuTemp.FileName);
                sb.Append(s);
                sb.Append("<br>");
            }
        }

        //Imprime o resultado em um label apenas para teste.
        ltlResultado.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```